# Is there an easy way to convert a SolidWorks drawing to an 3d flash file?

Tags: flash, 3d-graphics, solidworks

My dad does a lot of designing in SolidWorks for his business, and I would like to take one of his 3D drawings and put it on the web on a product page. Is there any way to easily convert that to flash?

Thoughts? Recommendations?

Comment: can you get abode flash ?

Comment: not in the near future

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not for free.  Could you get your dad to convert his file to DWG?  There are [solidworks community pages](https://forum.solidworks.com/thread/25543;jsessionid=02570D27E8AC364B7176EB20964CB3F2.node0) with macros that will do that.  Once you have a dwg file, there are a few tools you can try.  I have not used any of them:

1. [FlashDWG](http://www.autodwg.com/dwg-to-flash/) (free trial)
2. [DWG to SWF](http://www.filetransit.com/view.php?id=27873) (shareware)
3. [DWG to Vector](http://www.verydoc.com/dwg-to-vector.html) $200.